# EntityFramework Update will not make the change

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

After running the code bellow, the item.Name still says "New Item".

what is wrong here?

```
item.Name = "Updated Item";

items.Update(item);

public void Update(Item item)
    {
        using (var context = new wirvar_masterEntities())
        {
            var key = new EntityKey("wirvar_masterEntities.Items", "ID", item.ID);

            var itemToUpdate = (Item)context.GetObjectByKey(key);

            if (itemToUpdate == null) return;
            itemToUpdate = item;

            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this, try the `ApplyCurrentValues` method on the object context after doing your `GetObjectKey`.  Then all the values should update.

Answer (score 3):

Wrong is that there is no change to save. You received your `itemToUpdate` from database and after data you replaced it with reference to item - EF never knew about any changes you did, because assigning `item` to `itemToUpdate` makes nothing. Instead that assigning try to use:

```
context.Items.ApplyCurrentValues(item);
```

Answer (score 0):

you are dealing with references ... rather map the properties, than thinking changing the pointer will do it!